# How can I create a Marimekko chart in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I couldn't find any thread in the community about generating a Mekko charts just using GSheets.

Does anyone how we can do that?

Here's how to do it in Excel: https://www.mekkographics.com/how-to-create-a-marimekko-chart-in-excel/

I have figured out how to almost get there with some data processing. For example, let's review the GDP by country and source, to visualize its distribution. I was able to get the Mekko chart, but I'm missing the countries in the X axis.

Here's the data and spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xVFf8_pbVj45W39qDs7MY5cLE_zf1YlJcSzvqWfazg8/edit#gid=1149840583&range=V1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Putting the names across the bottom isn't possible in this way, you will either have to do it manually with text boxes or use a chart subtitle to identify each column.*

#### More Information:

There is a great tutorial on how to set up Marimekko charts in Google Sheets [here](https://medium.com/@jhsu98/start-using-a-mekko-chart-to-monitor-recurring-revenue-9dcf6c42eda6) which details how these charts can be made, though the takeaway here is that there isn't a direct way to add axis-labels using the chart itself.

#### Feature Request:

In this case, I would suggest that you let Google know that this is a feature that is important for Google Sheets and give them the idea to have it implemented.

From the Google Sheet UI (from the page in which you can see an open Spreadsheet), follow the `Help > Help Sheets improve` menu item and detail in the following `Send feedback` modal the information for this request.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) also exists as a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, though as this is normally for developer tools such as Apps Script or APIs, the best course of action would be the aforementioned `Send feedback` option from the UI.

There is however an already similar feature request on Issue Tracker asking for the inclusion of Mekko charts in Data Studio - this request can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110100398).

Comment: Thanks @rafa-guillermo! That's helpful and I'll definitely will add the feature request. However, can you clarify how would you go about "use a chart subtitle to identify each column" so the country names appear in the graph? the sheet is opened to edits if you want to make changes to accomplish it. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Mel I would personally do something like `Mexico | Germany |  USA | Spain | Viet Nam | Gambia` etc separating each country with a pipe (`|`) in order - the only issue of this is it becomes long after a lot of bars. I think in this case, superposing some text over the bottom might be better.

Comment: Thanks Rafa, I was hoping to get some advice in order to add the countries programmatically from the list (not manually since values will be changing). Also the GDP data is an example, but my dataset is different. I know how to add the labels but seems there's no option to move them to the bottom (and use line reference for the smaller areas)

Comment: just confirmed that there's no workaround. Wonder if someone could create a script haha, but thanks for the suggestions